# How to display image over image on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

I know this question might has been answered a few times. But I need a solution that works with any images.

I have a portoflio with 4 images in it. So it displays images, and I want to display an image of Github logo on hover.

I already found this :

```
a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5); /* your background */
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

But it needs a width and an height. My images don't have the same height so I need a css/jQuery/angular code which will fit to the image hovered.

Thanks !

Comment: Try: `width: 100%; height: 100%`.

Comment: Attach the hover functionality to a parent container and just swap the images, something like `.parent:hover .child {display: inline}` etc

Comment: set the `height:auto` `width:xxxpx` equal to the other logo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on, it will always cover it's parent. You may edit background position to fit your needs.

```
a:hover:before {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      background: url('img-path.png') no-repeat;
      background-position: right bottom;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%; 
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
```

**EDIT:** The hovered a-tag should use `position: relative;`

Comment: Yep ! I forgot it but sure I have : : `a : {position: relative;}`Thanks it works, I didn't think about the 100%:)